# Swift check type of object

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, types

I want to compare types of objects in swift.
I've got a function which takes an object of NSError as parameter. It should return a custom string.

It looks like this:

```
static func getLocalizedErrorText(error: NSError) -> String{
    switch error {
        case is NoConnection: //class NoConnection: NSError
            return "....."
        ...
}
```

But the function is not working as expected. I think the main problem is that this example is not working:

```
var dummy = MySubError() //class MySubError: MyBaseError
var dummy2: MyBaseError?
dummy2 = MySubError()

if dummy.dynamicType == MySubError.self {
        //This will work
}

if dummy2.dynamicType == MySubError.self {
        //This will not work
}
```

How can I check which type the parameter got?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for a type using

```
if error is MySubError {
    // do stuff
}
```

You can also do an optional cast, which will succeed, if the type matches or return nil, if not:

```
let subError = error as? MySubError
```

which you can also use in a `guard` predicate or `if let` statement:

```
if let subError = error as? MySubError {
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
guard let subError = error as? MySuberror else { return }
```